# how to use participles as adverbials

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

Would you please tell me whether the use of the participle clause is correct in the following sentence:

> Our young children are fascinated with the old-day musicians, TV shows and the life before they were born, **becoming** fans of some old artists, even **showing** their emotions for the one who passed away decades ago.

Comment: Should be *...fascinated with **old-time** musicians, TV shows...*, not ***the old-day***.

Comment: The use of the participle clauses is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence would improve with a couple of omissions. Unless you have identified the musicians and the person who died, omit **the** in front of them, ditto in front of **life**. **The** (the definite article) is generally used ahead of something/someone who has already been introduced.

Also, although you can speak of **the old days**, in this context, as a modifier ahead of **musicians**, we would refer to **olden day (musicians)** to mean **in the past**.

Our young children are fascinated with [the] old**en**-day musicians, TV shows and [the] life before they were born, becoming fans of some old artists, even showing their emotions for [the] one who passed away decades ago.

However, in answer to your query, your construction is otherwise fine.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-olden-days-in-olden-days

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article-the